# Chartjs 2.5.0 -> Labels below the chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I really need help because I can't find a workaround for my problem.

I just need the labels to be under the graph, like this (the default is on top):

[image: example]

I know there is the `generateLabels()` function, but with this I lost the click and hide/show function that I wanted and have with the defaults labels.

**UPDATE**
I find a "workaround", in version 2.5.0 , line 6713 -> change 'top' to 'bottom'. I know is not the ideal solution, but it works and is just what I need.
[image: example]

Comment: can you show some code what you have tried?

Comment: With the generateLabels I just get the "<ul class="0-legend"><li><span style=.......round-color:#C377C7"></span>Others</li></ul>". The others option is in the options object, but I can't find nothing to put there. var data = {
          type: 'pie',
          data: {
            labels: LABELS,
            datasets: [{
              backgroundColor: COLORS,
              data: VALUES
            }]
          }
        };

Comment: what exactly you want? you want label below your chart?

Comment: Yes. I just want the labels exactly like the picture I shared.

Comment: This is the default location of legends in highcharts. like shown here. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-legend. I can't immediately see version history though....

Update... I read wrong. This is clearly about ChartsJS and not highcharts. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I find a "workaround", in version 2.5.0 , line 6713 -> change 'top' to 'bottom'. I know is not the ideal solution, but it works and is just what I need.

[code printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNwiI.png)

Answer (score -1):

As per my thinking you can put label below your pie chart using `legendTemplate`

Here is fiddle : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TZq6q/307/)

then you can change your legend visualization as per your need.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I think this way does not work in version 2.5.0. But even if it works I'm going lose the event click the show/hide the content in the pie chart that exists with the default labels.